# Java InterruptedException - I'm confused as to what it even means for a thread to be interrupted or why it would be

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

I keep getting this exception inside of a synchronized block, in which I call wait on the same object I'm synchronized on. What does it mean for a thread to be interrupted first of all?
secondly, what are normal scenarios where this would happen? any advice as to what could be going on or what I should do?

Comment: Can you post some code please so we can see the context of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The interrupt mechanism is used to inform a thread that it should terminate itself as soon as possible. This allows the interrupted thread to exit safely without leaving any data in an inconsistent state.

Comment: For more information, I suggest reading Java Concurrency in Practice, especially the chapter "Cancellation and Shutdown."

Comment: I would like to point out that interrupt doesn't necessarily mean to end the processing. It just sets a flag and throws InterruptedException. How the interrupted thread reacts is purely its problem. It can be used to shift processing states or as a restart initiator. It just tells the thread that something fundamental changed and that the current execution state might no longer be valid or useful or desirable or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

> What does it mean for a thread to be interrupted first of all?

It means that something has called `Thread.interrupt()` on the thread object.  This sets the `interrupted` flag on the thread, and causes *certain* method calls to terminate with an exception.

> Secondly, what are normal scenarios where this would happen?

It is typically used when a second thread wants to tell this thread to stop what it is doing.  The call could be direct, or it could be done by a library method.  For instance, [`ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow%28%29) uses interrupts to (try to) terminate executing tasks.

Note that interrupting a thread does not guarantee to stop it.  Indeed, barring the cases where an exception is thrown, the thread will only notice that it has been interrupted if it calls `interupted()` or `isInterupted()`.  Even then, it could simply clear the flag and continue as if nothing has happened.

> Any advice as to what could be going on or what I should do?

Take a look at what is "controlling" the thread that got interrupted.